# Is this function rational?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is this function $\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{\left(\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(z-j^2)\right)^n}$ rational?

I think it is not rational since it looks like it is not meromorphic. I think every square integer is an essential singularity. But I do not manage to prove it.

Comment: Suggestion: try writing each summand as a Laurent series around $z=0$ (or the initial terms of its Laurent series); the sum can't be meromorphic at $z=0$ if the Laurent series of the sum contains arbitrarily negative powers of $z$.

Comment: And how do you do in my particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_m=\sum_{n=0}^m\frac1{\left(\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(z-j^2)\right)^n}$ is the partial sum to $n=m$ and $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{\left(\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(z-j^2)\right)^n}$ the limit function, if $f$ has a pole of order $N$ at some $k^2$, then $(z-k^2)^Nf(z)$ is bounded on a small disc centered at $k^2$;

Note that for $k$ even and $\epsilon >0$ one has $f(k^2+\epsilon) >  f_m(k^2+\epsilon)>0$ for any $\epsilon>0$ small enough so $f,f_m$ are continuous there since the terms for $n$ even are even powers hence positive, while the products with $n \ge k+1$ odd have $n-1-k$ negative factors, hence are positive too; for $k$ odd  we have $f(k^2-\epsilon) >  f_m(k^2-\epsilon)>0$, since now we have an extra change of sign for $n \ge k+2$ odd, while the even $n$ are positive as before.

Let $m=N+k+1 \ge k+1,$ so $(z-k^2)$ appears in the denominator of the $m$th term at least, one has $(z-k^2)^Nf_m(z)=\frac{h(z)}{(z-k^2)^{k+1}}$ where $h$ is analytic and non zero on a small disc centered at $k^2$ hence $|h| \ge A >0$ there- it's easy to actually write an explicit bound but not needed.

But then if $k$ even we get $\epsilon^Nf(k^2+\epsilon)>A\epsilon^{-k-1} \to \infty$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ contradicting the fact that $(z-k^2)^Nf(z)$ is bounded on a small disc centered at $k^2$, while if $k$ odd, we get $|(k^2-\epsilon)-k^2|^Nf(k^2-\epsilon)>A|k^2-\epsilon-k^2|^{-k-1} \to \infty$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, so contradiction again.

Note that unfortunately if $f(z)=\sum_{n \ge 1} c_n(z)z^{-n}$ and $c_n$ analytic on some fixed disc, $c_n(0) \ne 0, n \ge n_0$, with uniform convergence on compact subsets of the punctured disc above, it doesn't follow that that $f$ has an essential singularity at zero in general as the example $0=1/z+\sum_{n \ge 2}\frac{1/n!-z/(n-1)!}{z^n}$ with series clearly locally uniformly convergent in the punctured plane shows!
Similarly $z=(z^2+1)/z+\sum_{n \ge 2}\frac{1/n!-z/(n-1)!}{z^n}$

Comment: Thank you for this very clever answer. You talked about a more theoretical proof. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: sadly i was wrong and in the general problem, one cannot conclude that $f$ has an essential singularity as noted above so one needs the special form of $f$; note also that the original solution didn't quite work for $k$ odd since then terms at $k^2+\epsilon$ alternate from $k+1$ on, but one can use $k^2-\epsilon$ in that case and the terms stay then positive for all $m$